# super Lyndon words

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras, free-lie-algebras

[Lyndon words form a basis for Free Lie algebras.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Lyndon_basis)

In this direction, I need the reference for the super Lyndon words for free Lie superalgebras.

Given the definition of super Lyndon words, how to associate Lie monomials to get a basis for Free Lie superalgebras?

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

An article you probably want to look at is [E. S. Chibrikov, "The Right-Normed Basis for a Free Lie Superalgebra and Lyndon–Shirshov Words", Algebra Logika 45 (2006), issue 4, pp. 458--483](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10469-006-0024-5). This contains information on constructing a right-normed basis for free Lie superalgebras through the theory of Lyndon-Shirshov words.

Comment: Thank you. Given the definition of super Lyndon words, how to associate Lie monomials to get a basis for Free Lie superalgebras? This is not given in this paper. Please tell where I can find this. Also, please tell why are we taking u is a Lyndon word in X and v^2 where v is a Lyndon word in X_1 ?